# how to find value of $x$ in following equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the value of $x$ in $(x^{2}+1)^{35}=0$?
we can find value of $x$ in $(x^{2}+1)^{2}=0$ by using algebraic identity i.e.
                         $$x^{2}+2x+1=0$$
                         $$x^{2}+x+x+1=0$$
                        $$x(x+1)+1(x+1)=0$$
                        $$(x+1)(x+1)=0$$
                        $$x=-1$$
but how do we find value of $x$ in $(x^{2}+1)^{35}=0$?

Comment: The solution you give to the simpler problem is false.  If you substitute $x=-1$ you get $( (-1)^2+1)^2=4\neq 0$.

Comment: $a^{35}=0\iff a=0$. Also note that $x^2+1>0$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Note that:$(x^2+1)^2=x^4+2x^2+1\neq x^{2}+2x+1=0$

Comment: The linear algebra tag is misleading. If you seek real solutions there are none. There are **two different** complex solutions. The main tool to use is: if $a b =0$ the $a=0$ or $b=0$. In the complex you have $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i).$

Comment: yes mine mistake..i

Comment: The very first line of your 'solution' is wrong: $(x^2+1)^2$ is **not** equal $x^2+2x+1$; it's $x^4+2x^2+1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real root of $(x^2+1)^{35}=0$, because
$$
(x^2+1)^{35}\ge 1^{35}=1>0.
$$
Now, find roots in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$,
\begin{align}
(x^2+1)^{35}=(x-i)^{35}(x+i)^{35}=0.
\end{align}
Thus $(x-i)^{35}=0$ or $(x+i)^{35}=0$. Therefore, $x-i=0$ or $x+i=0$.
$$
\therefore x=\pm i
$$

Comment: but (x+iota)(x-iota)=x^{2}-1 because iota=-1

Comment: Comments also apply MathJax. What is iota? is it $i$? then $i=\sqrt{-1}$, not $-1$.